# how can conditionally show/hide gridlines on the yAxis using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using Chart.js for the very first time, I am using a radar chart and I would like that the yAxis line(which goes from 0 to 100 with a stepSize of 10) will be shown only on the even numbers and also change the gridline color to be grey and thicker, and in case the value is odd simply do not show the gridline at all, this is what I got so far, I know I have to use a callback to get to the object I am aiming but I cannot get the way to access to it:

```
 buildChart = () => {
    const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");

    myLineChart = new Chart(myChartRef, {
      type: "radar",
      data: {
        labels: ["Fifa20", "CS:GO", "Dota 2", "LOL", "Overwatch", "Fortnite"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Games",
            data: [40, 45, 53, 45, 100, 13],
            backgroundColor: [
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent",
              "transparent"
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
              "rgba(203,166,255,1)"
            ],
            borderWidth: 5,
            pointBorderWidth: 0,
            pointBorderColor: "transparent"
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scale: {
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            fontSize: 7,
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              switch (value) {
                case 20:
                  return value;
                case 40:
                  return value;
                case 60:
                  return value;
                case 80:
                  return value;
                case 100:
                  return value;
                default:
                  return "";
              }
            }
          },
          angleLines: {
            display: true
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            color: "#cac7c7",
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              if (value % 2 === 0) {
               Chart.defaults.global.options.gridLines.display = false;
              }
            }
          },
          pointLabels: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold"
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(Chart.defaults.global);
    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
        <canvas id="myChart" ref={this.chartRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you want to use a callback to achieve what you're looking for.

In order to only show gridlines for 20, 40, 60 and so on, you can define `scale.ticks.stepSize: 20`. To make the gridlines thicker, define `scale.gridLines.lineWidth: 5` for example.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: "radar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Fifa20", "CS:GO", "Dota 2", "LOL", "Overwatch", "Fortnite"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Games",
      data: [40, 45, 53, 45, 100, 13],
      backgroundColor: [
        "transparent",
        "transparent",
        "transparent",
        "transparent",
        "transparent",
        "transparent"
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
        "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
        "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
        "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
        "rgba(203,166,255,1)",
        "rgba(203,166,255,1)"
      ],
      borderWidth: 5,
      pointBorderWidth: 0,
      pointBorderColor: "transparent"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        display: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        stepSize: 20,
        fontSize: 7,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          switch (value) {
            case 20:
              return value;
              break;
            case 40:
              return value;
              break;
            case 60:
              return value;
              break;
            case 80:
              return value;
              break;
            case 100:
              return value;
              break;
            default:
              return "";
          }
        }
      },
      angleLines: {
        display: true
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: true,
        lineWidth: 5,
        color: "#cac7c7"
      },
      pointLabels: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontStyle: "bold"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```